# Is this an aggregation or composition association?

Tags: java, uml

I have an Album class and a Track class. Tracks can exist independently of an album, but an album cannot exist without any tracks.

I'm thinking that it's an aggregation because tracks are not destroyed when an album is destroyed. But specific tracks that belong to a specific album will be destroyed with the album... so can someone make this more clear?

Also, this is homework but this isn't the actual question. We're doing a huge modelling exercise and this is a single association link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the non-homework world, this is where the use cases decide the design.

If tracks are independent entities and albums are collections of tracks, that's fine.  However, under such a system, deleting an album would not mean deleting the tracks.

... Unless you had an option "delete tracks with album"

... Or you decided that a track would be deleted only when all albums are no longer containing it.

... And you had a "un-categorized tracks" album which cannot be deleted.

It sounds like you need to determine how you intend to use your application before you decide that the data model supports the exact usage pattern you might want to support.

Answer (score 4):

An Album *is a* collection of Tracks. A Track *is associated with* zero or more Albums. There exists such a thing as a Track without an album. As such, an Album is an *aggregation* of tracks. A track can be on more than one album (conceptually; consider Greatest Hits collections!), so it's clearly inappropriate to destroy a track because the first album it was part of got deleted.

If an object can exist in more than one collection simultaneously, or can exist independently of that collection, or should not be destroyed when the collection is, it is an *aggregation*.

Why do you want to destroy the tracks when you destroy the Album? If a track has *zero or one* albums, and will never be removed from an album once added, composition might be more appropriate- but this reads a lot more like aggregation, and your "tracks that belong to a specific album should be destroyed with the album" might not be on the right track.

Composition and aggregation are separate primarily for that reason: you need to be aware of when it's unsafe to assume that an object has become unreferenced just because a collection containing it has been (it is unsafe to assume that for an aggregation, not for a composition), and if you want to destroy something just because its collection went away, it probably is a Composition- but if that's not how you're using it, something has probably gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

From the first part of your question I'd say it's not Composition.  If a track can outlive its album then by definition its lifecycle isn't dictated by that of the album.  Therefore it's not composition.

I'd even question whether it's Aggregation - but then that depends on your particular definition of Aggregation since it's so notoriously badly defined in the UML spec.

Based on the info you give I'd more than likely model as a straight many:many Binary Association, on the basis that the domain rules you're trying to capture are:

1. Each album includes one or more tracks
2. Each track can appear on one or more albums.

However there's a bit of your question I don't really understand:

> But specific tracks that belong to a specific album will be destroyed with the album...

Can you elaborate?  What differentiates a track that is destroyed with its album from one that isn't?

hth.